# How do I solve this problem to use psql? | psql: error: FATAL: role "postgres" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, psql, ubuntu-20.04, createuser

I'm having trouble using PostgreSQL. I have recently installed this version (13+223.pgdg20.04+1) of postgresql package in ubuntu 20.04.

I'm trying to run `psql` command, but I get the following error:

> psql: error: FATAL:  role "my_username" does not exist

I have tried to create a new user with `createuser me`, but I get the following error:

> createuser: error: could not connect to database template1: FATAL: role "my_username" does not exist

I have tried also forcing the postgres user with `createuser me --username=postgres`, but I get the following error:

> createuser: error: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"

How do I solve these problems to use PostgreSQL locally on my computer without these problems?

PD: I have reinstalled postgres and now I'm getting a different error while doing `psql`:

> psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
> Is the server running locally and accepting
> connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why I had a bad installation, but I have completely uninstalled postgres following this post:

https://kb.objectrocket.com/postgresql/how-to-completely-uninstall-postgresql-757

after that I have restarted my computer and installed posgres again following the proper instructions in:

https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/

and now it looks like it works without problems

Answer (score 10):

first check user postgres exists:

**$ id postgres**

Then:

**$ su - postgres**

Password:

**$ psql**
psql (15.1 (Debian 15.1-1.pgdg110+1))
Type "help" for help.

If, Password for user postgres is no known then change it:
$ su - postgres

Password:
*su: Authentication failure*

**$ sudo passwd postgres**

New password:

Retype new password:

*passwd: password updated successfully*

Finally again:

**$ su - postgres**

Password:

**$ psql**

psql (15.1 (Debian 15.1-1.pgdg110+1))
Type "help" for help.

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide username in the `psql` command using -U option.

```
psql -U postgres
```

`Postgresql` comes with a predefined superuser role called `postgres`. If you want to create more roles, you first have to connect as this initial role.

Comment: It didn't worked, but I have reinstalled postgre (I had 2 versions and I have uninstalled both and installed the last version) and now the command "psql" shows a different error:

psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Answer (score 3):

Peer authentication means (there are advanced possibilities, but those are not going to be used by default, while the simple method is the default for apt-installed PostgreSQL) that you have to be the OS user 'postgres' to connect as the database user 'postgres'.  So you would do:

```
sudo -u postgres createuser me
```

You don't need to specify `--username=postgres`, since that is the default behavior anyway once you use `sudo -u postgres`

Alternatively, you could change your pg_hba.conf to use a different authentication method other than peer, if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

As your regular user, (as opposed to as postgres or other user), start the server with the following command:

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

The response will be:

```
 * Starting PostgreSQL 14 database server                  [ OK ]
```

Then, to get into the psql command line:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

If successful, you will get a message and prompt like this:

```
psql (14.8 (Ubuntu 14.8-0ubuntu0.22.04.1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```